# Notifications not showing on list

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-5

I have a django app with `django-notifications-hq` installed. The notifications are working pretty well except for the list of notifications aren't showing on the field. The notifications count is showing in the navbar.

Here's my code :

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bell" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M8 16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2H6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2zM8 1.918l-.797.161A4.002 4.002 0 0 0 4 6c0 .628-.134 2.197-.459 3.742-.16.767-.376 1.566-.663 2.258h10.244c-.287-.692-.502-1.49-.663-2.258C12.134 8.197 12 6.628 12 6a4.002 4.002 0 0 0-3.203-3.92L8 1.917zM14.22 12c.223.447.481.801.78 1H1c.299-.199.557-.553.78-1C2.68 10.2 3 6.88 3 6c0-2.42 1.72-4.44 4.005-4.901a1 1 0 1 1 1.99 0A5.002 5.002 0 0 1 13 6c0 .88.32 4.2 1.22 6z"/>
      </svg> {{ request.user.notifications.unread.count }}
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
      {% for notification in notifications %}
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ notification.target.get_absolute_url }}">
          Notification: {{ notification.actor }} {{ notification.verb }}
        </a>
      {% empty %}
        <span class="dropdown-item">No notifications</span>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to consult ChatGPT but don't get any answers. So any help from this community would be a great one. Also, if you need me to post anything else, I would definitely post it here.